# Python / Django - Safest way to normalize relative paths cross-platform?

Tags: python, django, path, pathlib, os.path

*Please note this question is about **relative** paths and must account for **cross-platform** functionality.*

When a user uploads a file, I want to generate a timestamped path to it:

```
def get_filepath(instance, filename) -> str:
    """
    Returns a timestamped directory path to deposit files into.

    i.e. "evidence/2023/02/23/96672aa5-94d9-4289-8531-d7a8dc8f060d/data.jpg"

    """
    dt = timezone.now()
    YYYY = dt.year
    MM = str(dt.month).zfill(2)
    DD = str(dt.day).zfill(2)
    UID = str(uuid.uuid4())

    # settings.MEDIA_URL = 'media/', I just checked
    path = (str(x) for x in (
        settings.MEDIA_URL, 'evidence', YYYY, MM, DD, UID, filename
    ))
    path = os.path.join(*path) # dubious
    return path
```

This is raising `SuspiciousFileOperation`, which is not at all surprising:

```
raise SuspiciousFileOperation(
django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: Detected path traversal attempt in '/media/evidence\2023\02\23\1cfa40b9-b522-4c70-b59b-fd270d722ab2\templeos.txt'
```

I'm at a loss as to how to normalize this though.

- `pathlib.PurePath` -- didn't work, Django `FileField` doesn't like the `Path` object, which want to treat the string as an absolute path by sticking `C:\` in front.
- `os.path.normpath` -- didn't work either (`SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path (C:\media\evidence\2023\02\23\cc32be4a-76d8-47c5-a274-9783707844b3\templeos.txt) is located outside of the base path component (C:\Users\...`)
- This does appear to work if I do `str(x).strip('/\\')` when defining the path, but this is hacky and the sort of thing I'd expect a proper library to handle...

What am I "supposed" to do to normalize *relative* paths such that this works on Windows and Linux?

Comment: URL will use  /, not \  in windows or linux.But path will use \ or /.

Comment: May ,you can have a look at djang's FileField , it can be setting.Then just do path.jon([YYY,MM,DD,UID,....]).not about the config ,media_url.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#filefield     The upload_to argument

Comment: You can also ,not save the file by your codes.Trye to use django's office way to save file.it can not change codes ,if you change local storge to others(not local) storage.

Comment: use like `upload_to="%Y/%m/%d"`,and save like Model(xxfile=xxdata).save()